# What does a cluster size mean?

Tags: database

When someone says "I have a cluster size of 6TB", what do they mean?

In terms of database size? Or in terms of the amount of data being processed at any given time? I don't know what this means.

Comment: "cluster" isn't a well defined word with 1 meaning, but in that sentence it probably means that they have a cluster of servers that have a combined total storage of 6TB.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I always got mixed opinions online and had to ask this question!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Do you have a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

That may depends of context.

If someone mentioned 6TB they probably are talking about storage.

Strictly cluster should be related to data chunks to be stored where related data should be stored in same cluster.

To understand database cluster you should understand first understand file system cluster which may be 4-8-16-32-64 ... KB for exemple where your data is stored in one or many clusters. For example, if your file system is planified to store big files then your cluster size should be bigger, performance is improved. If you want to store small files then your cluster should be smaller in order to optimize space usage.

In database your goal should be to be able to store related data to same cluster, in this case performance is optimized.

Anyway, 6TB is not anything which could make sense, so, this is probably related to storage space (or many storage sum).

you may want to check following doc to get idea :
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/clustrs.htm#ADMIN018